# Dynamic XML Sorting using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I sort dynamic XML using LINQ having following precedences:

1. Sort by **node-name**
2. Sort by **node-value**
3. Sort by **attribute-name**
4. Sort by **attribute-value**

Comment: what is dynamic about the XML? can you give us example (small) XML doc to work from?

Comment: In fact, what does sort mean in this context?

Comment: @Matt XML will have dynamic nodes, dynamic their values and their order. The XML data is unidentfied. There are hundreds of patterns of data.

Comment: Your question should be refined: the attributes have no order, thus has no sense to sort by something is not ruled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sorting by Node Name:**

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<data><carrot /><apple /><orange /></data>");
var sortedByNames = doc.Root.Elements().OrderBy(e => e.Name.ToString());

foreach(var e in sortedByNames)
    Console.WriteLine (e.Name);
```

**Sorted by Node Value:**

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<data><thing>carrot</thing><thing>apple</thing><thing>orange</thing></data>");
var sortedByValue = doc.Root.Elements().OrderBy(e => e.Value.ToString());

foreach(var e in sortedByValue)
    Console.WriteLine (e.Value);
```

It all follows the same pattern... You sort based on the criteria you define in the selector function passed into the `OrderBy` method.

Comment: @Brian I won't be sure about the nodes. XML is a response xml which will be dynamic.

Comment: I think you can take the initial `doc` as just an example XML. The rest of the code will work with any XML document.

Comment: @Ramiz Uddin: These examples make no assumption about the names of the nodes.  If you need more, you need to be more specific.

Comment: @Brian will that sort be nested?

Comment: No.  You didn't ask for a nested sort.  Consider using `Descendents()` instead of `Elements()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = from item in xmldoc.Descendants("content")
           orderby (string)item.Element("title")      // by node value
           //orderby item.Attribute("something")      // by attribute value                         
           select new 
           {
               Title = (string)item.Element("title"),
           };
```

Comment: I'm new to linq.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  To be able to dynamically pass in the name of the attribute I wanted to sort on.  Now to figure out how to dynamically do asc/desc and be able to pass in the number of params to sort on.  Thanks.